# Java Swing GUI code changes making no difference

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am making a GUI for a poker game with Swing, I am writing the action listeners for the buttons, I originally wrote an action listener for the Check button that SYSOUTs "BUtton Listener Works" just to check that it works.

I have changed this code to write some proper listeners and by some magic the GUI that is rendered still sysouts that quote... In the code below I delted the listener for check button and added one to call but this change is ignored somehow

I even deleted the action listener completely, saved everything and still it writes out this phantom code!

Additionally the JComboBox in ButtonBar does not show.

TLDR no matter what I do to the code for my GUI, it shows the result of old code.

Please someone save me.

```
public class ButtonBar extends JPanel {

 public ButtonBar() {
  setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Moves:"));
  JButton checkButton = new JButton("Check");
  JButton callButton = new JButton("Call");
  JButton raiseButton = new JButton("Raise");
  JButton foldButton = new JButton("Fold");
  JLabel selectPlayStyle = new JLabel("Select opponent play style");

  callButton.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Sherbert Lemon"));

  //create the comboBox
  String[] playStyleStrings = {
   "Tight Aggressive",
   "Tight Passive",
   "Loose Aggressive",
   "Loose Passive"
  };
  JComboBox < String > playStyleList = new JComboBox < String > (playStyleStrings);
  playStyleList.setSelectedIndex(0);
  playStyleList.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("none"));

  //DELETE THIS

  setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

  /*this is a class where you can establish where all of your Swing bits and bobs will go.*/
  GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

  //These show you how much space is allocated to each row
  gc.weightx = 0.2;
  gc.weighty = 0.2;

  //moves button column - all the JLabels
  gc.gridx = 0;
  add(checkButton, gc);

  gc.gridx = 1;
  add(callButton, gc);

  gc.gridx = 2;
  add(raiseButton, gc);

  gc.gridx = 3;
  add(foldButton, gc);

  gc.gridx = 4;
  add(selectPlayStyle, gc);

  gc.gridx = 5;
  add(playStyleList, gc);
 }
}
```

### `App`

```
public class App {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  /*Swing likes to manage it's own thread so this allows it to do so.
  This creates a Swing Thread and runs the method inside of it for you */
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    //main window for the application to load into
    JFrame frame = new MainFrame("Tren Poker Systems");
    frame.setSize(1000, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
   }
  });
  GameManager gm = new GameManager();
 }
}
```

### `MainFrame`

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

 private OddsPanel oddsPanel;
 private CardsPanel cardsPanel;
 private ButtonBar buttonBar;
 private static JTextArea gameInfoArea;

 public MainFrame(String title) {
  super(title);

  //Create Swing components.
  gameInfoArea = new JTextArea("Game information will be found here: ");
  oddsPanel = new OddsPanel();
  cardsPanel = new CardsPanel();
  buttonBar = new ButtonBar();

  //Set layout manager.
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  Container container = getContentPane();
  container.add(gameInfoArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  container.add(oddsPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
  container.add(cardsPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
  container.add(buttonBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
 }

 public static void addToGamePane(String information) {
  gameInfoArea.append(information + "\n");
 }
}
```

Comment: `it shows the result of old code...I even deleted the action listener completely, saved everything and still it writes out this phantom code` Do you mean delete, save, and *compile*?

Comment: On suggestion of a peer I used the eclipse clean function and have built the project again.

But now all I get is "Error: Could not find or load main class GUI.App"

Comment: Is there a main method in your project?  Sounds like your project configuration says your main is somewhere it's not.